# Gesture handler not working on BottomSheet

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to use gorhom bottomsheet in expo where I followed the installation instruction by doing `expo install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler` and `yarn add @gorhom/bottom-sheet@^4`. In my code managed to get the bottomsheet to show up but upon swiping up it doesn't move.

code.js

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetView } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";

const LandScreen = () => {
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <View className="bg-red-200 flex-1">
      <BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} snapPoints={["13%", "95%"]}>
        <BottomSheetView>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LandScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React native gesture handler needs some additional steps for it work properly on some devices. According to the documentation, its said that we need to wrap the entry point with `<GestureHandlerRootView>` or `gestureHandlerRootHOC`.

```
<GestureHandlerRootView className="bg-red-200 flex-1">
      <BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} snapPoints={["13%", "95%"]}>
        <BottomSheetView>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
        </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheet>
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```